# Referencing an object through a second object or keep a local copy?

Tags: c#, performance, reference

I'm developing a game using C# and was wondering about the performance of referencing object like this every frame:

```
object1.object2.object3
```

Or should I keep a reference to object3 locally? Is there any significant speed difference?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on so many things... you should profile boths in your context.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Depends on the numbers of calls. I usually prefer a member in that case. Read more about [what things cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What's significant to someone might be insignificant to someone else. It definitely costs more to have more object dereference operations but that might not matter. I'll assume that it does:

There are two costs to having an addition dereference operation:

1. The cache line that `object2` sits in must be fetched from memory if not already present. If it is likely to be already present, this cost is zero.
2. We can only load the cache line of `object3` if we have obtained a pointer to it. Therefore, a chain of dereference operations force sequential execution and prevents out-of-order execution (to an extent). OOO exection is a significant part of why modern CPUs are getting faster although clock rates do not.

If you don't have an intuitive understanding of how big these costs are you have no choice but to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a reference to object3 locally will definitely improve the performance.

Comment: Do you have measurement  to support that?